# Hibernate: Query only a few properties of the associated entity on a many-to-one association

Tags: hibernate, projection, many-to-one

I have two entities: **A( x, y )** and **B( r, s, A )**

**x, y, r** and **s** are properties of the entities and entity **B** has a **many-to-one** association with entity **A**.

I want to fetch all of my **B** entities. So, I do this:

```
List<B> myBs = session
    .createCriteria(B.class)
    .list();
```

As the **B** to **A** association is lazy, the **A** for each **B** is loaded only on demand. But, I don't want this. So, I do:

```
List<B> myBs = session
    .createCriteria(B.class)
    .setFetchMode("A", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .list();
```

Now, I get all my **Bs** with their respective **As** in a single shot. Each **A**, comes with all their properties (**x, y**). But, I want only **x**.

I tried this:

```
List<B> myBs = session
    .createCriteria(B.class)
        .createCriteria("A")
        .setProjection(Projections.alias(Projections.property("x"), "x"))
        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(A.class))
    .list();
```

And get the error: **QueryException: could not resolve property: x of: B**. Apparently, the result transformer is not being applied to **A**, but to **B**.

My question is: how do I `.list()` my **Bs**, fetching their respective **As**, bringing only the property **x** for each **A**?

Comment: Instead of createCriteria("A"), use createAlias("A", "a") and call class A property with alias 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this personally. But this will work i believe.

```
session.createCriteria(B.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("r").as("r"))
        .add(Projections.property("s").as("s"))
        .add(Projections.property("a.x").as("x")))
    .list();
```